# Как сделать чтобы посетители моего сайта задавали мне вопросы, а я мог давать на них ответы?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте, я бы хотел создать простенький сайт. Вся его функция заключается в том, что посетили задают мне вопросы, а я даю на них ответы и чтобы эти вопросы и ответы отображались на сайте. Напишите пожалуйста можно ли сделать это на HTML и код этого, если нет, то на каком нибудь другом языке. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Можно-можно, этот сайт тому примером.

Comment: Поищите любую бесплатную CMS которая поддерживает вопросы,ответы/комментарии/отзывы.

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы вам здесь написали "код" сайта в ответе?))))) Я вас огорчу, но это в десяток строк не уложится

Comment: На HTML - нет. Надо использовать скрипты на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте готовые решения. Например, [disqus](http://disqus.com/). Как пишут на главной странице:

> От маленьких блогов до массовых веб-сайтов, Disqus это самый простой способ создания активных сообществ. Он бесплатный и работает практически с любым типом веб-сайта.

Как это работает можно смотреть в живую здесь (внизу страницы): http://learn.javascript.ru/intro